# Update query getting suspended in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I am in between the development of a report and the main data set of the report is being populated using a stored procedure. One particular update statement is as given below

```
UPDATE T1 
SET 
  T1.Status=T2.Status, 
  T1.ErrorMessage=T2.ErrorMessage, 
  T1.IssueStatus=T2.IssueStatus
FROM 
  #tmptblOtherSongs T1 
  INNER JOIN #tmpOtherSongStatus T2 ON 
    T1.SongCode= T2.SongCode AND 
    T1.SocietyCode= T2.SocietyCode AND 
    T1.TableName=T2.TableName 
WHERE  
  T1.SessionID='TRYFBGHk' AND 
  T2.Status IS NOT NULL
```

The sp goes into a suspended state when it reaches this particular update query. I tried running the query alone, but the result was the same.It runs fine for small amount of data, as in thousands but the issue occurs for more amount of data.
Is there any way in which I can prevent this. I have no clue why this is happening.

Comment: Adding an index to the table to speed up this query will likely solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When the process is in suspended state, it is waiting for something. Quite often it's either waiting for I/O (reading or writing data, can be also tempdb related), or waiting for blocking to end.

If there is no blocking, it's most likely I/O operations. You should look at execution plan if there's something that doesn't look right and / or set statistics io on and check what tables are causing most of the I/O.

I/O can most often be improved by adding indexes, and in your case I would start looking at T1.SessionID and after that T1 & T2.SongCode and SocietyCode + maybe TableName depending on how many rows there are in the table per single value.

Comment: Thanks JamesZ.. But wouldn't adding an index slow down the process of update ?

Comment: @Geethu Only if you add index to those fields you're actually updating, in this case Status, ErrorMessage and IssueStatus